# Efficient grouping with count of items

Tags: python, pandas

Here is how my dataset looks like:

```
Name | Country
---------------
Alex | USA
Tony | DEU
Alex | GBR
Alex | USA
```

I am trying to get something like this out, essentially grouping and counting:

```
Name | Country
---------------
Alex | {USA:2,GBR:1}
Tony | {DEU:1}
```

### Works, but slow on LARGE datasets

Here is my code that does work on smaller dfs, but takes forever on bigger dfs (mine is around 14 million rows). I also use the multiprocessing module to speed up, but it doesn't help much:

```
def countNames(x):
    return dict(Counter(x))

def aggregate(df_full,nameList):
    df_list = []
    for q in nameList:
        df = df_full[df_full['Name']==q]
        df_list.append(df.groupby('Name')['Country'].apply(lambda x: str(countNames(x))).to_frame().reset_index()) 
    return pd.concat(df_list)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Alex','Tony','Alex','Alex'], 
                'Country':['USA','GBR','USA','DEU']})[['Name','Country']]

aggregate(df,df.Name.unique())
```

Is there anything that can speed up the internal logic (except for running with multiprocessing)?

Comment: Yes, don't use a `for` loop. Do you really want to store data as `{USA:2,GBR:1}` e.g. a dictionary in a cell? You lose a lot of Pandas functionality doing that

Comment: Which is fine, since the output needs to be written into a CSV. Any suggestions how to replace the `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially a cross tabulation.  You said "something like this" which implies that you aren't quite sure what the output should be.

**Option 1**
Group by and `value_counts`

```
df.groupby('Name').Country.value_counts()

Name  Country
Alex  USA        2
      GBR        1
Tony  DEU        1
Name: Country, dtype: int64
```

To get your specified output:

```
pd.Series({
    name: pd.value_counts(d).to_dict()
    for name, d in df.groupby('Name').Country
}).rename_axis('Name').reset_index(name='Country')

   Name               Country
0  Alex  {'USA': 2, 'GBR': 1}
1  Tony            {'DEU': 1}
```

---

**Option 2**
However, I'd prefer these representations.  Which we can see a number of ways to do this in [the answer to question # 9 in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47152692/2336654)

```
pd.crosstab(df.Name, df.Country)

Country  DEU  GBR  USA
Name                  
Alex       0    1    2
Tony       1    0    0
```

Comment: Nice way of getting the series of interest indeed.

Comment: I love Option 2 a lot, but I encounter this error: 

`TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`. Any idea why?

Comment: did you switch `name` and `d`?

Comment: @piRSquared, I am talking about Option 2, which is the crosstab function.

Comment: @ka_boom yeah, that's weird.  I'd need to see the data your using and the exact commands your running to understand why that is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Alex','Tony','Alex','Alex'], 
                'Country':['USA','GBR','USA','DEU']})[['Name','Country']]

df = (df.groupby('Name')['Country']
         .apply(lambda x: str(x.value_counts().to_dict()))
         .reset_index(name='Country'))
```

Returns:

```
   Name               Country
0  Alex  {'USA': 2, 'DEU': 1}
1  Tony            {'GBR': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an O(*n*) complexity solution, use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Alex','Tony','Alex','Alex'], 
                   'Country':['USA','GBR','USA','DEU']})[['Name','Country']]

c = Counter(map(tuple, df.values))

# Counter({('Alex', 'DEU'): 1, ('Alex', 'USA'): 2, ('Tony', 'GBR'): 1})
```

**Dictionary result**

You can then get a Name -> Country dictionary mapping via [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). I would not put dictionaries in a `pandas` dataframe, it's not designed for this purpose.

```
tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)
d = tree()

for k, v in c.items():
    d[k[0]][k[1]] = v

for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)

# Alex defaultdict(<function <lambda>>, {'USA': 2, 'DEU': 1})
# Tony defaultdict(<function <lambda>>, {'GBR': 1})
```

**Dataframe result**

For display purposes, you can build a dataframe directly from the `defaultdict`:

```
res_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').fillna(0)

#       USA  DEU  GBR
# Alex  2.0  1.0  0.0
# Tony  0.0  0.0  1.0
```